Forestplot with missing CI in R
I am conducting a systematic review and meta analysis and will be creating forest plots for different disease stages. Some studies provide only mean value without confidence interval.
I saw a post similar to what I want to do, however, I am unable to make it work for my data in a way that also gives the final pooled diamond or the CI lines for all cases. The similar post (Forestplot tweak needed for a missing CI in meta-analysis)
I have a part of my data in a atable format below. I would really apprecitae if the output is with single dots in places of missing CI. I need it to look neat, with a solid diamond shape as I have seen codes that give a rigid looking rhombus.
Thank you!

